# Is there no GetFilePointer(Ex) Windows API function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, file-pointer

I am trying to debug a program that manipulates a file. For example, I set the file-pointer to offset 4 (using a base of 0), but it seems to be starting at offset 5 instead.

To try to figure out what is happening, I want to put in a line to print out the current file pointer (I’m not using an IDE for this little project, just Notepad2 and the command-line). Unfortunately there does not seem to be a Windows API function to retrieve the current file pointer, only one to set it.

I’m recall being able to find the current file pointer in Pascal (in DOS), but how can the current file pointer be determined in C++ in Windows?

Comment: (For the record, it turned out that it was working correctly; I was just using the wrong test file. After I finished testing the size-based mode, I started testing the offset-based mode and forgot to start using the offset-based test file instead of the size-based test file. Doh! `›_‹`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unlike most functions, that provide both a getter and setter (in the read-write sense), there is indeed no `GetFilePointer` or `GetFilePointerEx`.

However the value *can* be retrieved by calling [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx)[`(Ex)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542.aspx). The two `SetFilePointer` functions return the  the return/output from `SetFilePointer`, but you have to make sure to specify an offset of `0`, **and** `FILE_CURRENT` as the mode. That way, it moves 0 bytes from where it is, then returns (I can’t vouch for whether or not it wastes CPU cycles and RAM to perform the zero-move, but I would think they have optimized to not do so).

Yes, it is inconsistent and confusing (and redundant and poorly designed), but you can wrap it in your own `GetFilePointer(Ex)` function:

```
DWORD    GetFilePointer   (HANDLE hFile) {
    return SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_CURRENT);
}


LONGLONG GetFilePointerEx (HANDLE hFile) {
    LARGE_INTEGER liOfs={0};
    LARGE_INTEGER liNew={0};
    SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liOfs, &liNew, FILE_CURRENT);
    return liNew.QuadPart;
}
```

Comment: Neither of your implementations contain error handling. The first one silently fails for files larger than 4GB. Neither one is desirable.

Comment: There are many cases where you know in advance that the file will NEVER be longer than 4 GB. In this case the code is OK.

Comment: Besides, this wasn't production code, it was just a sample for answering the specific question. Error handling is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @IInspectable, what is wrong with the second implementation, other than not checking for `SetFilePointerEx` return status?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe If the [`SetFilePointerEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex) API call fails, the value returned through `lpNewFilePointer` is *indeterminate*. It could be anything, but the code moves on to just return it, unconditionally, thereby promoting invalid data to reliable data. A corollary of this is that now every client using `GetFilePointerEx` is broken, too.

Comment: @Elmue Even in that case (which I will challenge will hold over time) it's just negligent to not be prepared for file sizes 4GB and up. [`SetFilePointer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) already returns this information. So you've performed the expensive operation (the function call), and then just waste it all by not caring. A non-truncating implementation is very likely just as fast.

Comment: @IInspectable: understood, that I did fix in my code immediately upon copying from here. Thanks for the detailed clarification. Why wouldn't you edit the answer and add the missing condition? You could return `-1` on failure, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17707021/1889329) is accurate: There is no API to query the current file pointer position. This functionality needs to be implemented in terms of [`SetFilePointer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) or [`SetFilePointerEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex), as noted in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointerex#remarks):

> You can also use `SetFilePointerEx` to query the current file pointer position. To do this, specify a move method of `FILE_CURRENT` and a distance of zero.

What's missing is a robust implementation that illustrates how to properly go about this. While that may seem trivial, the contributions so far leave a lot to be desired, specifically around error reporting. Since this is an abstraction there are decisions to be made.

The first one is obvious: Should the API provide a 32-bit interface (akin to `SetFilePointer()`) as well? Of course not! There's no convincing reason to artificially truncate the returned value at the API boundary in support of clients who wish to evaluate how long their assumptions hold. And with that, we can also retire the idea of calling `SetFilePointer()` and decrypting its error reporting scheme. The implementation will use `SetFilePointerEx()`.

The remaining decisions aren't as clear-cut, namely the mechanism for error reporting. The following is a list of possible alternatives:

- C++ exceptions

  - `+` Obvious function interface
  - `+` Errors cannot be silently ignored
  - `-` Larger binary (x64) or slightly more code (x86)

  ```cpp
  #include <Windows.h>
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <system_error>

  /// @brief Returns the current file pointer position.
  ///
  /// @param h File handle identifying the file
  ///
  /// @return Returns the current file pointer position on success.
  ///         Errors are reported via C++ exceptions.
  [[nodiscard]]
  int64_t get_file_pointer(HANDLE h) {
      LARGE_INTEGER li{};
      if (!::SetFilePointerEx(h, {}, &li, FILE_CURRENT)) {
          auto ec = std::error_code(::GetLastError(), std::system_category());
          throw std::system_error(ec);
      }
      return li.QuadPart;
  }
  ```
- [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected)

  - `+` Obvious function interface
  - `+` Errors cannot be silently ignored
  - `+` No exceptions
  - `+` Can return arbitrary error information
  - `-` Requires C++23

  ```cpp
  #include <Windows.h>
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <expected>

  /// @brief Returns the current file pointer position.
  ///
  /// @param h File handle identifying the file
  ///
  /// @return If the function succeeds, the return value holds a `value()`
  ///         with the file pointer position.
  ///         If the function fails, the return value holds an `error()` of type
  ///         `HRESULT` with additional error information.
  [[nodiscard]]
  std::expected<int64_t, HRESULT> get_file_pointer(HANDLE h) noexcept {
      LARGE_INTEGER li{};
      if (!::SetFilePointerEx(h, {}, &li, FILE_CURRENT)) {
          auto const hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());
          return std::unexpected(hr);
      }
      return li.QuadPart;
  }
  ```
- [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)
  This is an alternative to `std::expected` that works with C++17.

  - `+` Obvious function interface
  - `+` Errors cannot be silently ignored
  - `+` No exceptions
  - `-` Transfers the burden of discovering the specific error to clients

  ```cpp
  #include <Windows.h>
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <optional>

  /// @brief Returns the current file pointer position.
  ///
  /// @param h File handle identifying the file
  ///
  /// @return If the function succeeds, the return value holds a `value()`
  ///         with the file pointer position.
  ///         If the function fails, the return value does not contain a value.
  ///         Call `GetLastError()` for additional error information.
  [[nodiscard]]
  std::optional<int64_t> get_file_pointer(HANDLE h) noexcept {
      LARGE_INTEGER li{};
      if (!::SetFilePointerEx(h, {}, &li, FILE_CURRENT)) {
          return {};
      }
      return li.QuadPart;
  }
  ```
- Using a sentinel to report failures
  Since the file pointer cannot be negative, returning a negative value (such as `-1`) can be used to communicate errors.

  - `+` No exceptions
  - `+` Can be translated to C
  - `+` Can be used where a stable ABI is required
  - `-` Errors can silently get ignored
  - `-` Error discovery is on the client

  ```cpp
  #include <Windows.h>
  #include <cstdint>

  /// @brief Returns the current file pointer position.
  ///
  /// @param h File handle identifying the file
  ///
  /// @return If the function succeeds, the return value is non-negative.
  ///         If the function fails, the return value is `-1`. Call
  ///         `GetLastError()` for additional error information.
  [[nodiscard]]
  int64_t get_file_pointer(HANDLE h) noexcept {
      LARGE_INTEGER li{};
      if (!::SetFilePointerEx(h, {}, &li, FILE_CURRENT)) {
          return -1;
      }
      return li.QuadPart;
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

As nobody felt inclined to post a 'fixed' solution for the basic functioning answer posted by @Synetech in all the years it has been up, I've decided to do so instead. Below are the two implementations, each roughly conforming to the relevant SetFilePointer method in usage, leaving it up to the consumer to decide whether they care about files larger than 4GB or not and perform the relevant error handling.

```
DWORD GetFilePointer(HANDLE hFile, OUT PLONG lpFilePointerHigh)
{
    if (lpFilePointerHigh != NULL)
    {
        /* Ensure lpFilePointerHigh is zero */
        *lpFilePointerHigh = 0;
    }

    return SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, lpFilePointerHigh, FILE_CURRENT);
}

BOOL GetFilePointerEx(HANDLE hFile, OUT PLARGE_INTEGER lpFilePointer)
{
    const LARGE_INTEGER liOfs = { };

    if (lpFilePointer != NULL)
    {
        /* Ensure lpFilePointer is zero */
        lpFilePointer->QuadPart = 0;
    }

    return SetFilePointerEx(hFile, liOfs, lpFilePointer, FILE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: What is `OUT`? That's not standard C++.